# Is it possible to make invisible commit to a GitHub repository?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I would like to make comments section for Jekyll that would use GitHub API and HTML forms and if possible little to none Javascript. And right now I'm wondering if anyone has achieved it.

Comment: You're trying to create an HTML form that causes the user to submit a commit to your repository?

Comment: @KevinWorkman exactly, might be researching on it if someone would confirm that indeed "invisible commits" are possible.
https://www.google.lt/search?q=html+form+put+method&oq=html+forms+pu&aqs=chrome.2.69i59j69i57j0l4.10514j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

No.

What you're talking about is not possible, for good reasons.

You could put together a server (not using GitHub Pages) that accepts form data and creates a commit using the GitHub API, but this is not exactly trivial.

You might be better off using something like [Disqus](https://help.disqus.com/installation/adding-disqus-to-your-site) for your comments.